# Messed with installing and uninstalling java

Tags: java, installation

I had some problem with my java versions and I wanted to have only java 1.7 and remove all other versions. I started uninstalling them. What I did was checked the alternatives of java using `sudo update-alternatives --display java` and removed them using the below command untill there are no alternatives.

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" \
"/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java"
```

Now when I check for the java version `java -version` it says `bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory`

But when I try to install java using the below command `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer` it gives the following message,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java7-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 454 not upgraded.
```

Seems like java 7 is there. But I cannot see it with `java -version` command.

I didn't cjanged the .bashrc file and it still has the java path as follows.

```
#JAVA HOME
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

I want a proper worling version of java 7. Please help me to get this done.

Comment: Do you really have `PATH=PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}` in your .bashrc? This is incorrect. Omit one `PATH=`.

Comment: What does `sudo update-alternatives --config java` outputs?

Comment: I cannot use intellij or eclipse at the moment since I don not ave java

Comment: Replying to RC : There were open-jdk6, oracle-java6 and openjdk7 as alternatives. That indicated oracle java7 as the best version

Comment: @laune: I corrected it. but still the problem exists

Comment: Did you try again - logout - login? Check `echo $PATH`?

Comment: I would `sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer` then `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and choose oracle java7

Comment: @laune : the output for echo $PATH is  '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.4//bin'

Comment: So if there's no java or javac in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin, something has gone wrong during the installation or later. This (below ./lib/) would be a very unlikely place for the ./bin/ with the executables.

Comment: @RC : Thanks. It solved my problem